# Evaluate constant inequation in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove this :

```ml
Goal forall a : R, (forall e : R, e > 0 /\ Rabs a <= e) -> a = 0.
```

This is what I've done so far :

```ml
Goal forall a : R, (forall e : R, e > 0 /\ Rabs a <= e) -> a = 0.
Proof.
  intros a H.
  destruct (classic (a = 0)) as [a_eq_0 | a_neq_0].

  - trivial.
  - apply (Rabs_pos_lt a) in a_neq_0 as Rabs_a_gt_0.
    pose (e := Rabs a / 2).
    cut (Rabs a <= e).

    * intro absurd_ineq.
      cbv [e] in absurd_ineq.
      apply (Rmult_le_compat_r (/(Rabs a))) in absurd_ineq.
      unfold Rdiv in absurd_ineq.
      rewrite (Rinv_r (Rabs a) (Rabs_no_R0 a a_neq_0)) in absurd_ineq.
      rewrite (Rinv_r_simpl_m (Rabs a) (/2) (Rabs_no_R0 a a_neq_0)) in absurd_ineq.
```

With the current goal being :

```ml
2 goals
  
  a : R
  H : forall e : R, e > 0 /\ Rabs a <= e
  a_neq_0 : a <> 0
  Rabs_a_gt_0 : 0 < Rabs a
  e := Rabs a / 2 : R
  absurd_ineq : 1 <= / 2
  ============================
  a = 0

goal 2 is:
 0 <= / Rabs a
```

Given `absurd_ineq : 1 <= / 2`, how can I tell Coq that this comparison evaluates to `False`, in order to then use the `contradiction` tactic ?

I have tried using `vm_compute` and `cbv` in hope that `absurd_ineq` is simplified, evaluated, to `False`, but no chance.

Thanks.

EDIT :
The statement `forall a : R, (forall e : R, e > 0 /\ Rabs a <= e) -> a = 0` wasn't the right one, `forall a : R, (forall e : R, e > 0 -> Rabs a <= e) -> a = 0` was.

Here's the proof :

````ml
Goal :
  forall a : R, (forall e : R, e > 0 -> Rabs a <= e) -> a = 0.
Proof.
  intros a H.
  destruct (classic (a = 0)) as [a_eq_0 | a_neq_0].

  - trivial.
  - apply (Rabs_pos_lt a) in a_neq_0 as Rabs_a_spos.
    pose (e := Rabs a / 2).
    cut (Rabs a <= e).

    * intro absurd_ineq.
      cbv [e] in absurd_ineq.
      apply (Rmult_le_compat_r (/(Rabs a))) in absurd_ineq; [| lra].
      unfold Rdiv in absurd_ineq.
      rewrite (Rinv_r (Rabs a) (Rabs_no_R0 a a_neq_0)) in absurd_ineq.
      rewrite (Rinv_r_simpl_m (Rabs a) (/2) (Rabs_no_R0 a a_neq_0)) in absurd_ineq.
      lra.
    * specialize (H e).
      apply Rlt_gt in Rabs_a_spos.
      apply Rgt_ge in Rabs_a_spos as Rabs_a_pos.
      cbv [e] in *.
      lra.
Qed.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part of Coq's real numbers are defined axiomatically (see e.g. here: https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Reals.Rdefinitions.html). This means that computation does not work as straight-forwardly as it works with e.g. integers or natural numbers.

In general, I tend to use the `micromega` tools for solving such trivial goals. You can find their full documentation here: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html
I found the tactic `lra` to be most helpful. For your particular example, the following code works for me:

```
From Coq
 Require Export Reals.Reals micromega.Psatz.

Goal forall a:R, (forall e:R, Rgt e  R0 /\ Rle (Rabs a) e) -> a = R0.
Proof.
  intros a H.
  destruct (Req_dec a R0 ) as [a_eq_0 | a_neq_0].
  - trivial.
  - apply (Rabs_pos_lt a) in a_neq_0 as Rabs_a_gt_0.
    pose (e := Rdiv (Rabs a) 2).
    cut (Rle (Rabs a) e).

    * intro absurd_ineq.
      cbv [e] in absurd_ineq.
      apply (Rmult_le_compat_r (/(Rabs a))) in absurd_ineq.
      unfold Rdiv in absurd_ineq.
      rewrite (Rinv_r (Rabs a) (Rabs_no_R0 a a_neq_0)) in absurd_ineq.
      rewrite (Rinv_r_simpl_m (Rabs a) (/2) (Rabs_no_R0 a a_neq_0)) in absurd_ineq.
      lra. lra.
    * specialize (H e). lra.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! However it feels a bit like cheating. I'll take this answer but if you have another solution that doesn't use automatic tactics, I'll take it !

Comment: You can always normalize your inequality as if it were made of symbolic expressions to `2 <= 1`, which evaluates, as an integer inequality, to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an issue in the statement you want to prove (e.g. a conjunction instead of an implication) ? The lemma looks to be trivial as it is stated, and its proof doesn't use many knowledge about the reals.

```
Goal forall a:R, (forall e:R, Rgt e  R0 /\ Rle (Rabs a) e) -> a = R0.
Proof.
  intros a Ha; destruct (Ha R0) as [He _];
    destruct (Rgt_irrefl _ He).
Qed.
```

Comment: Indeed ! I didn't know you could do that (pass a second parameter to `Rgt_irrefl` for it to return `False`), thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually you're right, there shouldn't be a conjuction be an implication indeed.